# How do I add to a list in a file while also being able to be written to?

Tags: python

I'm trying to do something along the lines of this: I need a way to set up a file and be able to add to a value to it each time the command is used.

All the file format will be this:

```
{} | {}.format(user.id, list_items)
```

I don't want list_items to be overwritten. I want them as a list and be able to added to.

Full Code:

```
with open('test2.txt', 'a+') as f:
    newf = new_list_file.png
    user.id = message.id
    list_files = file.name
    f.readlines()
    if user.id in f:
        f.write(newf)
    else:
        f.write('{} | [{}]'.format(user.id, newf)
```

When each new person that uses this command, it will add them in my registry and what file they uploaded. I need the list updated without rewriting the list. Hence why the if statement is there.

Comment: `'{} | {}'.format(user.id, list_items)`

Comment: Not quite clear. Add a little more explanation as well as sample case.

Comment: Can you please provide more detail? Give an example of the actual contents of the file. Also explain what content you want to add to the file and where it should be inserted.

Comment: `with open("file.txt", "r+"):
    perform operations`

If you provide more detail we can give a more concrete answer

Comment: You don't want to use a text file for this.  Use the `shelve` module or a database instead.